# What's the Windows "PORTPROMPT:" printer port?

Tags: windows, printer

When selecting the port for a new printer in Windows you can pick LPT1, COM2, etc. There's a FILE: option that does a "Print to File" (it's been around for many versions of Windows).

I see on my Win8 system that there's a new port called "PORTPROMPT:" that I never noticed before. I can't seem to find any documentation about it. What's it do differently than the old FILE: option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PORTPROMPT is indeed the replacement of FILE.

From [Building Print-To-File Solutions for Windows 8 - Firmware Encoding Index](http://feishare.com/attachments/article/236/building-print-to-file-solutions.pdf):

> PORTPROMPT is a new port type that performs the functions of FILE but is updated to work with v4 drivers and handle printing to file from apps running in low-rights mode.

That begs the question what a v4 driver is.

From [V4 Printer Driver - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh706306.aspx):

> The v4 printer driver model was designed to address known issues with the version 3 driver model, and thus improve the quality of the experience that users have with their printers. [...]
>
> The v4 print driver model is also optimized for several new scenarios including the following:
>
> - Metro style scenarios. [...]
> - Printer sharing. [...]
> - Ease of driver development. [...]

Comment: As a total aside, what's up with Microsoft putting documents like that up as DOCX downloads rather than just put the article as a webpage in the first place?